# The nearest object from the array of objects

Tags: arrays, math, search, machine-learning, bigdata

I need to find the most `similar` to desired `object` from the large array of objects.

In this case `object` - something with only numeric values which we must compare(for example below it's `x` and `y` coords).

By `similarity` we mean minimal sum of differences between the corresponding values.[image]

How can I do this in the most quickest way?

P.S. Array of objects can be sorted before searching if needed.

P.S.S. I already asked this question on the math.stackexchange.com, but some users said that I can also find something here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
This is generally for specific programming questions.  "quickest" depends much on the language in use, but you've posted no code.

Comment: @Prune I just need something for start. I even don't know what languages can solve this issue and how, I don't know how I can find methods which solve this task. If you are know something about the subject please share it, no matter what language.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [distance function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29).  The simplest is to take the differences of corresponding coordinates; take the absolute value of each difference; add those up for all coordinates, and that's the distance between the two sets of points.  In more algebraic terms:

Let's call the reference array D (for Desired), with points (Dx1, Dy1), (Dx2, Dy2), ... and the target array (Tx1, Ty1), (Tx2, Ty2), ...  You have 10 targets in the above example.

```
|Dx1 - Tx1| + |Dy1 - Ty1| +
|Dx2 - Tx2| + |Dy2 - Ty2| +
...
```

That's your distance between D and T.
Do this for all ten targets, and report the least-distance target as the best match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the most simple and obvious answer, and it's good with the small data set. But unfortunately if we will have large data arrays it's almost unreal to calculate them all. So due to this problem I asked this question.

Comment: Then you'll have to refine your problem statement.  If you want to choose the match with the minimal sum of differences, information theory demonstrates that you *must* compute the sum of differences in some way.  If you have data of certain characteristics, it's feasible to cluster them and save computing distances to clusters known to be distant from the "desired".  However, that clustering requires a non-trivial amount of computation, as well -- in distances.

Comment: Can you explain the part about clusterization? I don't understand what exactly I should to do. Maybe you can explain it via my sample in the post? Also I don't understand how can I store precomputed distances to the desired values if desired object every time is different?